# Easiest way to read and write a multidimension array?

Tags: java, android, io

I'm trying to store an int array on the device but I'm not sure where to start. The array data looks like this:

```
myArray[1][1] = 5;
myArray[1][11] = 4;
myArray[2][1] = 2;
...
```

I've looked at many tutorials on reading and writing but none seem to cover this topic and I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around I/O in general.

Comment: What is *problem* with this *easy* approach?

Comment: I think he wants to store it on the device, without it being gone after the application closes. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, J. Maes. To clarify, I need to be able to read and write it to and from an external file somehow.

Comment: I think you should never use arrays in java except for educational (e.g. homework) purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work to save the array into the file :

```
 try {
         PrintStream file = new PrintStream(new File("file.txt"));
         for(int row = 0; row < myArray.length; row++)
         {
             for(int col = 1; col < myArray[0].length; col++)
             {
                 file.println(myArray[row][col]);
             }
          }

         }
        catch(IOException e) {
         //Handle the exception
         }
```

Comment: Better, use `PrintWriter` instead. However, you can also use `DataOutputStream` to store the integers as integers (4-byte).